# Why couldn't command prompt recognize ~dp0?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch

I'm having similar problems since months when I start batch files, but I was able to modify them to work by explicitly giving paths. Now Steam gave me this message, when trying to run a game for the first time:

`Windows can't find ~dp0\VC_redist.x64.exe`

I checked the Path variables, and everything exists which exists on a newly installed Windows, if they are involves in.

Comment: Try to replace this line in your bat to: **`"%~dp0\VC_redist.x64.exe"`**

Comment: That is the original code. I replaced it with `"%~dp0%VC_redist.x64.exe"`, and it seems it worked. Thank you for pointing to the code which may cause the problem.

Comment: If you want to do it right, you should still go with the example @It_Wasn't_Me showed you. `%~dp0%` is ***weird***.  It ***probably*** works becuase %~dp0 ends with a backslash and the second "%" gets thrown away.  It's still wrong even if it works.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas 
This also works with one or two backslashes, I would say that the added **`%`** is wrong, but also that it is ignored by the interpreter, since the presence of **`%`** does not interfere with the result, and removing, there is the same

Comment: @It_Wasn't_Me, I thought that was what I said (more or less).  ;-)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Sí Señor!